# azure webapp app settings slow to appear in webapp

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm

I'm deploying a web app using terraform, this has some app configuration settings. Some of the settings are static, others are key vault references. Once this is deployed I'm using source control to deploy and build a small application.

Once the app is running, the configuration is not there. If I wait 5 - 10 minutes it appears. If I SSH into the app via the portal, I can see that this isn't present in the environment variables for x minutes . Is there any reason why it takes so long, is there anything I can do around this?. It's odd, as I can see the configuration in the portal with key vault references being correctly resolved, this is before oryx has finished building.

I don't think this is related to terraform, pseudo code below. I just wonder if there's an app setting or something I can do around this even if it's stoping the application (python) starting until it has configuration. I just would have expect this to be there once the web app was crated?

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {

  app_settings = {
    environment = "static"
  }

  site_config {}

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned" 
  }
  
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault....
  ]

}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "app" {
  app_id   = azurerm_linux_web_app.app.id
  repo_url = ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous nature of app settings updates could explain the delay in configuration being present in environment variables.

The `WEBSITE ENABLE SYNC UPDATE SITE` application setting can be used to make the update synchronous, which means that the source control deployment will start only after the application settings have been completely updated.

Refer [MS Doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references.md) for more relevant information regarding key vault references for Azure App services.

I tried running the terraform template from [terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app) with few modifications to resolve your error and it worked as expected.

```bash
app_settings = {
WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = "true"
}
```

**Note:** Once deployed, check the application settings in the app service's configuration section.

***Output:***

[image]

*Deployed with the relevant configuration:*

[image]

You can also check under `diagnose and solve problems` under an app service for the availability and other application changes as well as performance issues of a Web app as shown below.

[image]

Comment: I tried that setting, as well as using a user managed identity that was granted access  to the key-vault and neither made any difference. Also I added static configuration, that isn't there either.

Comment: Can you try by creating a new template for deployment ! @TimTharratt